# Running an IF statement in MS VBA using a similar field from two tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set a quantity value based on a sum of the current quantity and then subtracting an amount based on a quantity value in another table.
My current thought process is: If QuantityA is less than or equal to Quantity B then subtract QuantityA from Quantity B.
I am no expert on SQL and MS VBA, so I was wondering how I can make an if statement with the two different tables.

```
Private Sub Command23_Click()

    If QuantityA <= QuantityB Then
        QuantityB = QuantityB - QuantityA

    Else
       MsgBox "You can not hire that many" & ToolName & "as there is only" & [DEPARTMENT TOOLS (stocked)].Quantity & "available"

    End If
        MsgBox "Your hire request has been successful"
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't know if this would be possible. but I am considering an IF statement where if the ItemID's Quantity is equal to or greater than 1, then subtract one from ItemID's Quantity and and record

Comment: Is this about VBA in MS Access?

Comment: Saving calculated data, especially aggregate data is usually a bad design. Should enter raw data and calculate aggregate data when needed. However, to pull data from another table for comparison, use recordset or domain aggregate functions (DCount, DSum, DLookup, etc).

Comment: @urdearboy to answer your question, I have a table for 'All Tools' that uses a simple add record function, allowing the user to insert raw data. This is then displayed in a report.
My 'Hire Tool' table uses information sourced from the 'All Tools' table to provide information such as a Tool ID, which is in a combo box to show other information such as the tool's name.
As each tool has a quantity number, I would like to make it so every time a tool is hired, it adds a record to the new table, as well as subtracting one from the quantity in the original table.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 yes sorry, I am using MS Access VBA

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're asking by opening a recordset containing the results of a query and comparing the values returned by the query. In order to restrict the query to the proper quantities you need to pass in the ID of the tool you are checking.

@June7 is correct about saving calculated data. The only time you would want to save it is if you are keeping a log of events or if speed of join queries becomes an issue (unlikely given proper DB structure)

```
toolId might be stored in a text box control for example
Function Something_Click(toolId as string)
  Dim rs as Recordset
  ' create a recordset containing data from the two tables
  Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT A.TOOL_QTY AS TOOL_QTY_A, " _
           & " B.TOOL_QTY AS TOOL_QTY_B, A.TOOLNAME AS TOOLNAME" _
           & " FROM TABLE1 AS A  " _
           & " INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B ON A.TOOL_ID = B.TOOL_ID" _ 
           & " WHERE A.TOOL_ID = '" & toolId & "'")
  ' compare the values in the table
  If rs![TOOL_QTY_A] <= rs![TOOL_QTY_B] Then
    ' your true condition, for example
    ' MsgBox "Success"
  Else
    ' your false condition, for example
    ' MsgBox "Oops, not enough of " & rs![TOOLNAME]
  End If
  ' close the recordset
  rs.close
End Function
```